# File download using javascript create duplicate line items

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, download, xmlhttprequest

`Java` based web-app is creating duplicate line items on a downloaded file(txt file) over a remote connection where the application is installed. On testing it locally,the file is downloaded as expected. But on the client environment, there are multiple servers/load balancers, the file creates duplicate entries every single time when downloaded through the web-app.But the actual file on the server(which is being downloaded) itself doesn't have duplicates.
So the download `js` code is doing something that happens only over a remote connection and not through localhost.

JS code makes `XMLHttpRequest` to the backend server and brings back data which is downloaded through the browser.

The data is getting concatenated twice for some reason.

Sample input file:

```
Test 123
Test 456
```

Downloaded file:

```
Test 123
Test 456
Test 123
Test 456
```

**The js code:**

```
jQuery('#submit-btn').on('click', function() {
    var name = jQuery(NAME_ID).val();
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('POST', getUrl('search'), true); -- call to backend server that brings back data
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
    request.responseType = 'blob';

    request.onload = function(e) {
        if (this.status === 200) {
            var blob = this.response;
            var filename = "";
            var disposition = this.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition');
            if (disposition && disposition.indexOf('attachment') !== -1) {
                var filenameRegex = /filename[^;=\n]*=((['"]).*?\2|[^;\n]*)/;
                var matches = filenameRegex.exec(disposition);
                if (matches != null && matches[1]) filename = matches[1].replace(/['"]/g, '');
            }

            if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
                window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
            } else {
                var downloadLink = window.document.createElement('a');
                var contentTypeHeader = request.getResponseHeader("Content-Type");
                downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([blob], {
                    type: contentTypeHeader
                }));
                downloadLink.download = filename;
                document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
                downloadLink.click();
                document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
            }
        }
    };
    request.send("name=" +name);
});
```

**Backend JAVA code:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "text/plain")
public @ResponseBody String search(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) {

    String log = "";
    String fileName = "";
    String useragent = "" + request.getHeader("user-agent");

    if (request.getParameter("name") != null) {
        fileName = request.getParameter("name");
    }

    
    try {
        log = readLogContent(fileName.trim());

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(50);
        if (useragent != null && useragent.indexOf("MSIE 6") == -1) {
            builder.append("attachment; filename=");
        } else {
            builder.append("inline; filename=");
        }
        
        builder.append(fileName);           

        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", builder.toString());
        response.setContentType(MimeTypes.getMimeType("txt"));

        OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
        try {
            os.write(log.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
            os.flush();
        } finally {
            os.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.debug(e);
    }
    return "";

}
```

**UPDATE**

How do I debug this JS code to examine the blob contents?
Its calling a url and executing the click event, not sure how to debug the payload before the download occurs. Any tips?

Comment: If there is an infrastructure issue we would not be able to reproduce it here, nor we have any details to understand it.

Comment: @aled - that's what I am concerned too. Is there any networking/load balancer related issue that could cause this behavior? Two clients reported this problem. And I cannot replicate it locally at all.

Comment: Many issues can cause that behavior, but Stackoverflow is not the appropriate site to discuss that. This is programming Q&A site, not a forum. If the issue is not related to programming then is off topic. Having said that, there are no details of the architecture to even guess, even if it not were off topic.

Comment: @aled : I am not a js expert. Do you see any issues with the JS code at all that could create duplicates?